# Kubernetes Ingress Controller GPC GKE can't reach the site

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, gke-networking

Kubernetes Ingress Controller can't reach the site

Hi, this is the first time I am trying to deploy an application with kubernetes. The problem I am facing is I want to be able link subdomains with my svc, but when I try to navigate to the links I get

> This site can’t be reached

I will explain the steps I made for these, probably I something is wrong or missing

1. I installed `ingress-controller` on google cloud platform
2. In GCP -> Networking Services -> Cloud DNS

   a. I pointed testcompany.com with google dns

   b. I created an A record pointing the public IP from the previous step "ingress-nginx-controller"
3. my svc manifest

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     namespace: staging
     name: testcompany-svc
     labels:
       app: testcompany-svc
   spec:
     type: NodePort
     ports:
       - name: test-http
         port: 80
         protocol: TCP
         targetPort: 3001
     selector:
       app: testcompany
   ```
4. my ingress manifest

   ```
   apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1

     - host: api.testcompany.com
       http:
         paths:
         - backend:
             serviceName: testcompany-svc
             servicePort: test-http
   ```

Everything is green and it seems to be working, but when I try to reach the url I get the `This site can’t be reached`

---

Update 1

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: staging
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: front.stagingtestcompany.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: testcompanyfront-svc
          servicePort: testcompanyfront-http

  - host: api.stagingtestcompanysrl.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: testcompanynodeapi-svc
          servicePort: testcompanyapi-http
```

Comment: Are you able to call your service internally? You can use a node’s internal ip address and nodeport to check it. Also,make sure the pod have a container listening on your TCP port 3001. Last thing, is your nodeport range between 30000-32767 or you customize it? More info by running this command, Kubectl get service -o yaml

Comment: did you try to reach directly the public IP instead of the hostname? with a curl, you can set the host like this `curl -H "Host: api.testcompany.com" <IP>` to avoid DNS latency or misconfiguration

Comment: What `ingress-controller` have you installed ? Could you provide the link ? Is it `ingress-nginx` or maybe `kubernetes-ingress` ? Could you also share your entire `ingress` manifest so we can see all the annotations etc. ? +1 to the above questions. Does it work properly when you `curl` the service IP directly ?

Comment: @Milad thanks for your comment. The ports from nodeport are between de default range. Locally it is working, but I do not have a domain locally. Thanks for your comment it is useful!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for your comment. If I try to access the ingress-nginx-controller external ip I've got 404.

Comment: @mario thanks for the comment. I updated the question with information of the manifest. I portforwared the pod and I can see the url working locally. I am doing something wrong with ingress and the domain (or something it is missing) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check this, in order:

1. your Service, Pod, Ingress are in the same namespace: `kubectl get all -n staging`
2. your Pod is listening on port 3001: run it locally if you can, or use `kubectl port-forward pods/[pod-name] -n staging 3001:3001` and try it locally with `http://localhost:3001/...`
3. your Service is reaching your Pod correctly: use `kubectl port-forward service/testcompany-svc -n staging 3001:3001` and try it locally with `http://localhost:3001/...`
4. check any other Ingress spec rules before the one you posted
5. check for firewall rules in your VPC network, they should allow traffic from Google LBs

Comment: thanks for the answer up to step 3 everything is working I should check the ingress spec rules and the firewall. thanks

Comment: Thank you @FaustoFusaro , your answer was really helpful to analyze everything. What I was missing was to setup the subdomains in the CGP Network DNS. Thanks